# Rtmp publisher package with null safety

Tags: flutter, stream, rtmp

I have tried many packages of rtmp publisher, but every package has null safety issues. I am new to flutter and the app I am making app which requires live streaming to rtmp url. I have rtmp url.
I have used this package and am trying to run it in vs code. https://github.com/pinkfish/flutter_rtmppublisher.
I am getting the following errors.

```
FAILURE:  Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':camera_with_rtmp:compileDebugAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':camera_with_rtmp:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :rtplibrary.
     Required by:
         project :camera_with_rtmp
      > No matching configuration of project :rtplibrary was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```